# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS Gmapping

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to modify the openslam sourcecode of GMapping algorithm. I have replaced the GridSlamProcessor class with GridSlamProcessor_Server class with the existing function as well as new methods. Now After running catkin_make I am getting several "undefined reference to..." error.
The errors are like---

```
CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/src/slam_gmapping.cpp.o: In function `SlamGMapping::init()':
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x1196): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::GridSlamProcessor_Server()'
CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/src/slam_gmapping.cpp.o: In function `SlamGMapping::startServer()':
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x33bc): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::initServer(std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/src/slam_gmapping.cpp.o: In function `SlamGMapping::initMapper(sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const&)':
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x63e9): undefined reference to 

`GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::setSensorMap(std::map<std::string, GMapping::Sensor*, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, GMapping::Sensor*> > > const&)'
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x67f6): undefined reference to `

GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::setMatchingParameters(double, double, double, int, double, double, int, double, double, unsigned int)'
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x687d): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::setMotionModelParameters(double, double, double, double)'
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x68ea): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::setUpdateDistances(double, double, double)'
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x6a13): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::init(unsigned int, double, double, double, double, double, GMapping::orientedpoint<double, double>)'
CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/src/slam_gmapping.cpp.o: In function `SlamGMapping::addScan(sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const&, GMapping::orientedpoint<double, double>&)':

slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x78b4): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::processScan(GMapping::RangeReading const&, int)'
CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/src/slam_gmapping.cpp.o: In function `SlamGMapping::laserCallback(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x7bbb): undefined reference to `GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::getBestParticleIndex() const'
CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/src/slam_gmapping.cpp.o: In function `SlamGMapping::updateMap(sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > const&)':
slam_gmapping.cpp:(.text+0x89e4): undefined reference to `

GMapping::GridSlamProcessor_Server::getBestParticleIndex() 

const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/collab/catkin_ws/devel/lib/gmapping_server/g_server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [slam_gmapping/gmapping_server/CMakeFiles/g_server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed

The result is something related to include statements..I am unable to debug it.Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259256/ros-gmapping/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-04-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is your new class linked ? you'll have to modify CMakeLists.txt for that

---

Originally posted by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) with karma: 115 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-04-17**:
There is no link for the classes in CMakelists.txt, actually both the existing and new classes are under same namespace, and in both the classes there are public methods having same name, I'm not sure whether those are creating troubles.

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-04-17**:
If possible can you please tell me how to link the new class by editing CmakeLists.txt

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-17**:
Sorry, can't write it here, but here is a link to cmake documentation on that matter : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html